# SQL query problem with spaces

Tags: php, sql

my following query is working for those countries whose name consists on single word like **Ukrain**, but its not showing any result for **United States**.

what can be the problem ?

```
    $states= mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT STATES AS states, 
COUNTRY from contries_cities WHERE COUNTRY like '{$country['country']}'");
```

Comment: Make sure you do not spell `United States` as `United%20States`

Comment: why u using like and not compare = , and do you sure that in united states is in the db

Answer (score 0):

DO NOT USE `mysql_*` FUNCTIONS, THEY ARE DEPRECATED AND NOT RECOMMENDED FOR PRESENT OR FUTURE USE!

That said, you should move to a better engine like [mysqli](http://il2.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or better yet, [PDO](http://il2.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).
Those engines support the **preparing** of queries, you should use that.